# How do I test for no whitespaces in a string, using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I test for no whitespaces in a string, using regex?
I'm using JQuery

```
var postcode = $(this), val = postcode.val();

if(val.test(NO WHITESPACE)){
   ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: If you were just looking for space characters, it would have saved some time and confusion if you had been more specific in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only spaces, you don't need a `RegExp`: no spaces = `val.indexOf(' ') < 0`

Comment: What about other forms of Whitespace like Tab characters, newlines, ...?

Comment: In that case a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is the better tool: no whitespace in string => `val.match(/\s/g) === null`

Answer (score 4):

```
if (/\s/.test(string)) alert("OH NO THERE IS FILTHY WHITESPACE IN THAT STRING");
```

The "\s" ... uhh, thing, in a regex means "any whitespace character".  Specifically, it means the same as this:

```
[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]
```

which is to say, space, form feed, line feed, carriage return, tab, vertical tab, and some space-like characters from extended Latin and Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
if(!val.match(/\s/)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code this would replace all the blank spaces..

```
string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')
```

In fact it would remove even newline characters

The spaces are actually removed by `\s`

Comment: This will not remove `all` the white spaces but only those at the begining and at the end of the string. And more, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = !/\s/.test('IHaveNoWhiteSpace')

valid ; //# => true

var valid = !/\s/.test('I Have WhiteSpace')

valid ; //# => false

var isValidPostCode = /^[a-z]{2}\d{3}[a-z]{2}$/i.test('TN809EX');

isValidPostCode ; //# => false
```